# Move an Item from the beginning of an Array to the end

Tags: jquery, arrays, push

I've got a set of ten questions in 5 topics. Each question is part of a multidimensional array of each topic. I need to shift the first question to the last position of this array, and then erase it. This way, the user will be asked the ten questions without repeating them and will be able to repeat them if he wishes to do so.

This is an example array:

```
var topic1 = [{
   "question":"Question1?",
   "ans1" :"Answer 1", "ans2" :"Answer 2", "ans3" :"Answer 3"
},
{
   "question":"Question2?",
   "ans1" :"Answer 1", "ans2" :"Answer 2", "ans3" :"Answer 3"
},
{
   "question":"Question2?",
   "ans1" :"Answer 1", "ans2" :"Answer 2", "ans3" :"Answer 3"
}
//and like that 'til qustion 10
]
```

After the user have answered the first question, I want if to move from position topic1[0] to the end of that array, so that  topic1[0] is now the second question.

I tried slicing the array and pushing it, to no avail, like this:

```
var moveThis = topic1.slice(0,1);
topic1.push(moveThis);
topic1.shift();
```

That actually pushes the array into itself... or something like that.

New question should always be in position [0] of the array, or the rest of the code won't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is: `slice` returns an array. So you have to use the first element of the array: `var moveThis = topic1.slice(0,1)[0];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
topic1.push(topic1.shift());
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
    var firstToEnd = function(array)
    {
        var first = array[0];
        array.removeAt(0);
        array.push(first);
    }
```

But why don't you show the current question and just change the current question to the next when the user answers it?

```
var current = 0;
var question = topic1[current];

var nextQuestion = function()
{
  current++;
  question = topic1[current];
}
```